# Why eclipse xml editor can't add bookmark?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Why eclipse xml editor can't add a bookmark?
And <kbd>Alt+Left/Right</kbd> doesn't work very well in xml editor.
Any plugin can solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

In Eclipse Juno (4.2) bookmarks can be added to xml files by double clicking on the most left bar (line numbers bar, for example).

Answer (score 1):

The double-click action might be bound to adding a Breakpoint for use during XSL Transformations.  You can still add a Bookmark from the left-hand ruler's context menu.  As for "And Alt+Left/Right doesn't work very well in xml editor.", [file a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=WTP%20Source%20Editing&component=wst.xml) with more detail.